# Clipping a video (spatially) using FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-editing

How can I clip a video spatially using FFMPEG, with no border added, and no quality degradation? 
So basically I just need to split the video into 4 parts to separate the videos, like the frame below:

[image]

Comment: What I see is *tiling* a video in a 2x2 layout. If that's what you want, it's not possible without re-encoding.

Comment: I see. So is there a way to do that at least without quality degradations?

Comment: @Mulvya could be done using HEVC tiles + some encoding constraints. Which is for sure not possible in this case but just wanted to mention this.

Comment: re-encoding is fine! How can I use a tile command?

Comment: I just don't want to decrease quality or get a huge file size-wise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer which worked perfectly for me, and the quality is almost intact:

```
ffmpeg -i input_320x240.avi -vf crop=<w>:<h>:<x>:<y> output_300x220.avi
```

w = Output width

h = Output height

x = X co-ordinate of output image in the input image

y = Y co-ordinate of output image in the input image

Comment: Obviously I, and others, have misinterpreted what you actually wanted to do in your question.

Comment: That's fine. Probably I was not clear enough.